# ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.operations.delete) HTTPError 404

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud, operation

I try to use cloud shell,
gcloud firestore operations delete [OPERATION_NAME],
I don't know the name OPERATION_NAME because get in error when type Buckets/backup-Name/folder-Name/,
Some information in the web site:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import ,
How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know operation you want delete you need to list all operation available. To list the operations use command:

```
gcloud firestore operations list
```

You can delete operation from the list, if there any.